# Lock hints on preconditions

Tags: sql-server, locking, constraint

Assuming for a moment that FK references are not available, what lock hints should be placed on the preconditions of the following example to prevent deadlocks and inconsistent data?

(This is a contrived example, of course, to illustrate a scenario in which a delete/update can only be performed dependent upon the state of some other table)

```
-- Schema
CREATE TABLE EntityTypes (
    EntityTypeID int NOT NULL, 
    Name nvarchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_EntityTypes PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EntityTypeID)
);

CREATE TABLE Entities (
    EntityID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    EntityTypeID int NOT NULL,
    EntityName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Entities PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EntityID)
);

-- Test data
INSERT INTO EntityTypes (EntityTypeID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Test 1');

-- Updater 1
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRAN;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Entities WHERE EntityTypeID = 1)
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('Cannot delete entity type which is referenced', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END

DELETE FROM EntityTypes WHERE EntityTypeID = 1;

COMMIT TRAN;

-- Updater 2
INSERT INTO Entities (EntityTypeID, EntityName) VALUES (1, 'Test Entity')
```

Environment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `EntityTypeId` is the primary key of `dbo.EntityTypes` then `REPEATABLE READ` would suffice:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
BEGIN TRAN;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Entities WHERE EntityTypeID = 1)
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('Cannot delete entity type which is referenced', 16, 1);
    RETURN;
END

DELETE FROM EntityTypes WHERE EntityTypeID = 1;

COMMIT TRAN;
```

The `NOT EXISTS` syntax Aaron suggested would also function as you require at `REPEATABLE READ`. The same would be achieved by specifying a hint on `dbo.Entities`:

```
DELETE et
FROM dbo.EntityTypes AS et
WHERE EntityTypeID = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM dbo.Entities WITH (HOLDLOCK)
  WHERE EntityTypeID = 1
);
```

Comment: Does the HOLDLOCK table hint makes dbo.Entities table SERIALIZABLE and hence the second example has lower concurrency than the first REPEATABLE READ example?

Comment: @TravisGan No, it will take the same locks as if run at `READ COMMITTED` but the lock will be held until `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why the "pre" condition? Why not:

```
DELETE et
  FROM dbo.EntityTypes AS et
  WHERE EntityTypeID = 1 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Entities
      WHERE EntityTypeID = 1
  );
```

Comment: Despite being a single statement, my understanding is that SQL Server will still only take an shared lock on the Entities during the select.  Is there some hidden magic I am unaware of?  If this pattern is extended for an insert on EntityTypes, we would end up with the other side taking a shared lock on EntityTypes followed by an Exclusive lock on Entities.  Since this would go in the opposite order (S on Entities, X on EntityTypes vs S on EntityTypes, X on Entities) it would still deadlock.  Furthermore, this does not carry the side-effects of the example.

Comment: @Mitch No hidden magic, I wasn't suggesting this as a complete solution, just a tidier way to write the code (and it didn't work for a comment). Since Mark has incorporated my syntax and actually thought about the problem, I'll delete.